# Why i'm getting exception when trying to get the file size from my ftp server?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

I need to get the file size so i can later calculate and report to progressBar the download size how much have been downloaded so far and how much still left to download.

In form1 i have a backgroundworker and this is how i'm sending the files to the class with the download method:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                int fn = numberOfFiles[i].IndexOf(txtHost.Text, 0);
                string fn1 = numberOfFiles[i].Substring(txtHost.Text.Length + 1, numberOfFiles[i].Length - (txtHost.Text.Length + 1));
                string dirs = Path.GetDirectoryName(fn1);
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(fn1);

                ftpProgress1.DownloadFtpContent(sender,numberOfFiles[i], dirs, filename);
            }
        }
```

Then in the method DownloadFtpContent i did:

```
public void DownloadFtpContent(object sender ,string file, string filesdirectories,string fn)
        {                       
            try
            {
                BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                string filenameonly = Path.GetFileName(file);
                string ftpdirectories = Path.Combine(ftpcontentdir, filesdirectories);
                string fileurl = "ftp://" + file;
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP;                
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fileurl);                                
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
                FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Int64 FileContLen = resp.ContentLength;
```

I see in the fileurl the directory and file name for example:

ftp://ftp.newsxpressmedia.com/Images/CB 967x330.jpg

But using breakpoint on the line:

```
FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

I'm getting exception:

WebException:

The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if the file is Exist or not on the Ftp Server. if the file is Exist than check the permission for File Access. if u don't have access permission of File than you can't get the File size.